# how to implement Create action on Order and Order Details on single Create View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

anyone came up with simple solutions?

question: Given the two model classes with a relationship of one-to-many, how can i design a single create for these..

how can i add order details collection to a order entity that is not persisted yet in the database? and what viewmodels will i use? 
given that i have Order page(master) that is completed form then i must have a partial view that collects order details and after that when i clicked 'save', it will create the 'Order' plus its collection of 'order details'. thanks

a simple solution of codes will be helpful. thanks

Here's my models:

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "0.00")]
        public decimal TotalAmount { get { return OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.Amount); } }

        public decimal Cash { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "0.00")]
        public decimal TotalBV { get { return OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.BV); } }

        public int MemberID { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderDetailID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get { return Product.Price * Quantity; } }

    public decimal BV { get { return Product.BV * Quantity; } }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why is there a one-to-many between order and details? Seems to me that one order should have one details entity (in which case you would not have this problem).

Comment: why not? you usually have an order with many line items

Comment: @Rewinder its Order header and Order line relationship

Comment: @Rewinder: its like in northwind database. i just want to create an order plus its details in one create view page in mvc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is really "it depends" :) The question you need to ask first (and it has nothing to do with MVC) is the following: when do you want to commit user entries? I can think of several options:

- You have a "create order" page. User fills the header fields (looks like Member is the only one), hits save, you save order in the database, get the order ID, make the header fields read-only and the user starts entering lines.
- The form has both header fields and detail fields on the entry form (personally, I find it confusing - but it's a matter of taste). You get all the data (probably in form collection) and build Order and Order details objects out of that (either in the controller, or through custom provider)

Additionally, you need to answer the same question about order details. Do you want to submit every row, or allow the user to create multiple rows (through some "Add Row" button and JavaScript code behind it) and then submit a set of rows.

Once you decide which way you want to go - it will be easier to design the form. If you run into problems - come back; I am sure you will get plenty of help!

God luck

Comment: your option 2 is like what i have created. but how can i collect order details first (ienumerable) then attach to the main entity order like Order.OrderDetails = IEnumerable<OrderDetails from page here>. i have used a 2nd submit button for a single order detail to be passed to controller and a ViewBag to collect all order details. i just cant implement it. the first submit was for the order entity that contains its order details

Comment: so, you get all fields through form collection (not sure where the need for second submit button comes from). Then you create Order. Then you loop through the fields for one order detail at a time and add to the order (order.OrderDetails.Add() - *not* OrderDetails = IEnumerable)

Comment: thanks. but the problem is how can i loop through form fields, im using a strongly-typed page.. i was thinking maybe a partial view for the order details?.. plus the order is not yet persisted in the database so i must get its 'generated id' first..

Comment: if you name the fields of the details properly (say, Detail1.OrderDetailID, Detail1.Amount, etc for the first detail; Detail2.OrderDetailID, Detail2.Amount, etc for the second) then you can just bind by prefix - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470808.aspx

I recommend that you start coding the view, figure out the big issues that I described above - and if you run into problems, ask questions. At this time your questions have become too theoretical. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how clever MVC's binding is since I use my own binding so I don't know whether it can do the binding to models *for* you.

What you can do is to number all the inputs for each line.  So `Product1`, 'Amount1`, etc.  For each new line (say there is an 'Add Detail' button) you create a new set of inputs with the next available number.

When you parse the `Request.Form` you simply ask for each line until you cannot find one --- then you know you are done.

HTH

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. will try that tonight. i was thinking about this blog [http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/] maybe i can use this technique, any more comments will be helpful. thanks

Comment: interesting :) --- I should take a closer look at that