# create/insert multiple entities simultaneously on one view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

[how to implement Create action on Order and Order Details on single Create View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368804/how-to-implement-create-action-on-order-and-order-details-on-single-create-view)

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/
is there any other simpler way to do this? MVC 3 style or in Razor View? thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Razor as your view engine will not make the process simpler, just more readable. And even using ASP.NET MVC 3 you'll have to pretty much end up following the [Editing a variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) post that you mention.

Of course, you can add a new row of fields dynamically completely in jQuery, without having to create an action method for it. Something like:

```
<div id="fields">
    <span class="row">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
</div>

<a id="add" href="#">Add another</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
            AddTextBox();
        });
    });

    function AddTextBox() {
        // clone the last span
        var newRow = $("#fields .row:last").clone();
        //clear any value the fields might have
        $("input", newRow).val("");
        //append it to the container div
        $("#fields").append(newRow);
    }
</script>
```

Still, the solution in the blog post encapsulates a new row of fields in a partial view which is rather clean.