# Create/Edit Parent and Child Form MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using C# and MVC3

I have a simple Entity Model

Entities:  Orders , OrderItems

Orders have 0 or more Order Items

I want to create a single page to create an order

While on this Page I would fill in the fields that are in the Orders table (Customer, Phone, Order Number...etc)

Then there would be a grid (I am using Telerik MVC grid).  I want to add OrderItems to this grid.  I was thinking of having s small form above the grid with its own submit button.  I can submit using ajax and refresh the grid using ajax.

At the bottom there would be a single submit button that coudl create the order and all the orderitems at once.

I can't seem to piece this enitre solution together.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Have you tried to implement this and got stuck at some point?

Comment: Honestly i cant visualize how this could/should all go together.  I am used to submitting a form and having that go into a database.  But that does not seem possible here because i am trying to submit order items so they will be "saved" and displayed in the list but i cant put then into the database because the order items must reference an order.  At this point the order has not been created yet.

Comment: You can use `Session` object to store current order values and then put it all to database in one move. Your question is to broad to answer fully.

Comment: I know i am sorry.  So If i have typical MVC form that submits to the [Post] Create action in the order items controller ..  Your saying i can store that OrderItem in a Session object?    Could you give me an example of what that [Post] Create action would look like and also what the coresponding Index action would look like to return an Ienumerable of Order items from the Session object?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: follow this post - [how to implement Create action on Order and Order Details on single Create View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6368804/1437962)

Basically, convert your code to partial views in your main view. Also separate order entry form from displaying the order list. Also you may find useful to look at this resource - [Empty Model with Partial View](http://forums.asp.net/p/1657368/4319330.aspx/1?Empty%20Model%20with%20Partial%20View)